# Excel VBA Total Column in 2D array Ubound

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I would like to total all the data in the column of a 2D array

My code below is broken, the code cycles through the contents of a 2D array and once the Column equals "Net Amount Local" I would like to pause and sum all the values within that Column (array dimension)

```
Sub Evaluate_PositionV()

Dim aMapRow As Integer, aMapCol As Integer
Dim Ttraded As Double

Ttraded = 0

For aMapRow = LBound(arrayTraded, 1) To UBound(arrayTraded, 1)
        For aMapCol = LBound(arrayTraded, 2) To UBound(arrayTraded, 2)
            Debug.Print arrayTraded(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                If arrayTraded(aMapRow, aMapCol) = "Net Amount Local" Then
                    for each i in UBound(arrayTraded, 1)

                            aMapRow = aMapRow + 1
                            Ttraded = Ttraded + arrayTraded(aMapRow, aMapCol)
                End If
    Next aMapCol
Next aMapRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't (re)use `aMapRow` as a counter for your innermost loop. Your indexing for `arrayTraded` should be `arrayTraded(i, aMapCol)`.

Comment: `For i = 1 To arrayTraded(i, aMapCol)` doesn't seem to be doing to job either, I'm a bit confused it has been a while since I have coded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this (I can't test this since I don't have your data):

```
Sub Evaluate_PositionV()
    Dim aMapRow As Integer, aMapCol As Integer
    Dim Ttraded As Double

    Ttraded = 0
    For aMapRow = LBound(arrayTraded, 1) To UBound(arrayTraded, 1)
        For aMapCol = LBound(arrayTraded, 2) To UBound(arrayTraded, 2)
            Debug.Print arrayTraded(aMapRow, aMapCol)
            If arrayTraded(aMapRow, aMapCol) = "Net Amount Local" Then
                For i = 1 To UBound(arrayTraded, 1)
                    Ttraded = Ttraded + arrayTraded(i, aMapCol)
                Next i
            End If
        Next aMapCol
    Next aMapRow
End Sub
```